# What are the measurement units of omega

Tags: trigonometry

What are the measurement units of $\omega$ in this equation and why

$$Y(x,t)=\,A\cos(kx-\omega t)?$$

Comment: You can write \omega

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What do you know about the units of arguments to the cosine function, and how units behave under multiplication and addition?

Comment: I know the units of t are seconds

Answer (score 2):

It is radians per second, so when you multiply $\omega$ by $t$, $\omega t$ has units if radians.

Comment: I was told that the units are sec^-1 but I dont understand why

Comment: $\omega t$ is just a number; $t$ has units of seconds, so $\omega$ must have units of reciprocal seconds.  You must distinguish between $\omega$ and frequency, which also has units of reciprocal seconds, but differs by a factor of $2\pi$.

Comment: Why is $\omega t$ just a number

Comment: Because you are taking its cosine.  The function can't be zero after 120 seconds and not-zero after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

$ \ \omega \ $ is called "angular frequency" in physics and engineering, and has units of radians/second.  Since radian is a "dimensionless unit" (because angle is defined as the ratio of arclength along a circle to the radius of said circle), the radian unit is often not written.